# Call to undefined function get_home_url() in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried to declare `get_home_url` in `header('location: "'.get_home_url().'"/');` but it creates an error call to undefined function.

Comment: no i didn't put this code in my functions.php

this is my code checking for login




`if (empty($username) || empty($password)) {
  header('location: "'.get_home_url().'"/?errmsg=Please input your account');
 }elseif ($count == 0) {
  header('location: "'.get_home_url().'"/?errmsg=Account does not exist');
 }elseif ($pass2 != $pass) {
  header('location: "'.get_home_url().'"/?errmsg=Incorrect Password');
 }else {
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
  header('location: "'.get_home_url().'"/');
 }`

Comment: Please do not dump code in comments. Edit your original post to add any new information.

Answer (score 0):

step 1: put ob_start(); before the include statement in your functions.php;

for example, you include your file header_redirect.php in your functions.php
you should do this in your functions.php:

```
.....//something also.
ob_start();
required '/header_redirect.php';
```

in your header_redirect.php file

```
header('Location:"'.get_home_url().'" ');
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<?php
if (empty($username) || empty($password)) { 
    wp_redirect( home_url()."/?errmsg='Please input your account'" ); 
}
else if ($count == 0) { 
    wp_redirect( home_url()."/?errmsg='Account does not exist'" );
}
else if ($pass2 != $pass) { 
    wp_redirect( home_url()."/?errmsg='Incorrect Password'" );
}
else { 
    session_start(); 
    $_SESSION['user'] = $user; 
    wp_redirect( home_url()."/" );
}
?>
```

I hope, this may help you.